# Create an object from a string

Tags: php, android, string, object, android-listview

I have a php code that returns a string (which is an array in reality) and in the android code I want to turn that string into an object, to be able to insert it into a listview...
This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require 'jsonwrapper.php';
mysql_connect("+++++","+++++++","++++++++");
mysql_select_db("my_tripleleon");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articoli");
while($raw=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{       $output[]=$raw;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to cast it in to an object?

Comment: no because http.execute() returns a string :S

Answer (score 0):

From your php-code you return a `json`-array.
In your Android application you make a web-request, parse your json-array (see `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes).

Comment: true. you return it as string, from android you make a web-request and get a `String`. you pass this `String`  to `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` constructor.